# How do I open/edit a *.xnb file in XNA Game Studio 4.0?

Tags: xna-4.0, sprites, fonts

I've downloaded a *.xnb font sprite, but I don't know how to open/edit it. I installed XNA Frameword 4.0 in VS 2010.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: You cannot open or edit it directly. But if you place the XNB file in the same directory as your XNA application its content can be loaded using XNA's content manager.

Comment: Like Roy said, you can place it into your program's content folder and then load it at runtime. Textures also have a method for saving them as an image, so you could essentially extract it that way.